# Tensor products of $L^2$ spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-analysis

Consider a probability space, $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$, and some arbitrary Hilbert space $H$ (in my case, a space of functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$). On an intuitive level is $L^2(\Omega,\Sigma,P;\mathbb{R})\otimes H\approx L^2(\Omega,\Sigma,P;H)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only on an intuitive level: Define the map $\Phi$ from the algebraic tensor product of $L^2(\Omega)$ and $H$ to $L^2(\Omega;H)$ by $f\otimes \xi\mapsto f(\cdot)\xi$. This map has the following properties

- $\Phi$ is isometric:
  $$\langle f(\cdot)\xi,g(\cdot)\eta\rangle_{L^2}=\int_\Omega f(\omega)g(\omega)\langle \xi,\eta\rangle_H\,dP=\langle \xi,\eta\rangle_H\int_\Omega f(\omega)g(\omega)\,dP=\langle f\circ\xi,g\otimes \eta\rangle_{L^2\otimes H}$$
- $\Phi$ has dense range:
  Let $F=\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{A_i}(\cdot)\xi_i$ be an elementary function. Then $F=\sum_{i=1}^n \Phi(1_{A_i}\otimes \xi_i)=\Phi(\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{A_i}\otimes \xi_i)$.

Thus, $\Phi$ extends to a unitary operator from the Hilbert space tensor product of $L^2(\Omega)$ and $H$ to $L^2(\Omega;H)$.

Comment: Then is there an advantage of writing it down as tensor space? At least to me, it is harder to go through the definitions of, and develop an intuition for, tensor spaces, than just imagining a random element in a Hilbert space

Comment: Defining $L^2(\Omega;H)$ is technically more complicated than defining the tensor product of Hilbert spaces (observe that the usual way of decomposing a function into positive and negative part does not work for vector-valued functions). Therefore $L^2(\Omega)\otimes H$ is sometimes used as a definition of $L^2(\Omega;H)$.